# Method parameter intellisence

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I have a list of strings which are valid inputs to a method. The list of strings is quite long and will probably be stored in a database(but not 100% necessary - could be in a resource file. I would like in an ideal world, validate that the string passed to a method is valid a bit like a enum. I don't want to create an enum as the list of inputs will be generated by calling out to another system. I want to be able to autogenerate the inputs be either updating a database or a resource file.

```
// Magic String
public void Test()
{
    var result =  DoSomething("myFieldName");
}

// would like myFieldName to be some sort of intellesence
public void Test()
{
    var result =  DoSomething(myFieldName);
}


public string DoSomething(string input)
{
    return $"Hello {input}";
}
```

I want to avoid passing magic strings around as there could be 100+ values and the developers are not going to be able to remember all possible inputs.

Thanks!

Comment: Create a class with your predefined properties, load the fields from where ever.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a class that has static read-only properties that return a value from the data source (which could be an app.config, database, or some other data store).

For this example I'm using the following app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SomePropertyName" value="Some Property Value" />
    <add key="MyFieldName" value="Another value" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Next we can create a class that has properties that represent the keys in the config, and the value of the property would be pulled from the configuration file. The sample class below has a private method that will return the value from the config (but it would be easy enough to replace the method with one that looked up the value from a database):

```
public static class ConfigKeys
{
    // Get-only properties that the developer can access
    public static string MyFieldName => GetString("MyFieldName");
    public static string AnotherFieldName => GetString("SomePropertyName");

    // Returns the actual string from the data source (app.config, database, etc)
    private static string GetString(string propertyName)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Then from the developers point of view, all they have to do is:

```
public static void Main()
{
    DoSomething(ConfigKeys.MyFieldName);

    // rest of code omitted
}
```